# How to get to a particular git tag

Tags: git, github

I want v0.1.27 of nodejs code base.

This is what I did.

```
git clone git://github.com/ry/node.git 
cd node
git checkout -b v0.1.27
```

However when I look at v0.1.27 code base changelog there I see changelog for 0.1.32 also. It seems I did not checkout v0.1.27.

How do I checkout a branch from a tag?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you did is create a **local** branch, called v0.1.27, starting from HEAD. If you only want to have a look at the v0.1.27 tag, just remove the `-b` option:

```
git checkout v0.1.27
```

If you plan to make changes, you might want to create a tracking branch:

```
git checkout -b --tracking my_v0.1.27 v0.1.27
```

Comment: +1 and to clarify on the "certain previous commit": It refers to the `SHA1 ID` that can easily be found via `gitk`. If I only need to "checkout" that file to a temporary location (i.e. not reverting), then I would use the `show` subcommand: `git show 82e54378856215ef96c5db1ff1160a741b5dcd70:MyProj/proguard/mapping.txt > myproj_mapping.txt`